# Spark joins failing Spark job always failing for joins (CDH 5.5.2, Spark 1.5.0)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We are running into frequent errors with spark standalone cluster with our newly installed CDH 5.5.2 cluster. We have 7 worker nodes each one has 16 GB memory. But, almost all joins are failing.

I have made sure i allocated full memory with --executor-memory and ensured it has allocated that much memory and by verifying it in Spark UI.

Most of our errors are as below. We have checked things from our side. But none of our solutions did work.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/spark-b9e69c8d-153b-4c4b-88b1-ac779c060de5/executor-44e88b75-5e79-4d96-b507-ddabcab30e1b/blockmgr-cd27625c-8716-49ac-903d-9d5c36cf2622/29/shuffle_1_66_0.index (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.getSortBasedShuffleBlockData(ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.java:275)
... 27 more
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:162)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:103)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
... 1 more
```

1. /tmp has 777 permissions, but it is still telling as /tmp has no permssions.
2. We have configured SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS to some other folder where we have better disk memory, but still the cluster is using /tmp, why.? we have changed it through Cloudera manager, and printed the spark.local.dirs in spark configuration in spark, which gives the folder that we set. But, when it comes to execution, it is other way. It is checking the files in /tmp. Are we missing any thing here.?
3. we have turned off spark-yarn, does any configurations of yarn impacting standalone?

Has any one faced this issue? and why is this recurring to us.? We had similar cluster with horton works, where we installed bare-bones spark ( which is not part of distribution), which worked very well. But, in our new cluster, we are facing this issues. May be we might have missed some things.? but curious to know what we missed.

Comment: Do you have same permissions on /tmp on all nodes? Ideally you may want to create spark specific temp directories that have appropriate permissions.

Comment: Hi Ravindra, on all nodes we have permissions. I have set to use other folder though for spark local dirs, but still why is it writing to /tmp.? I have verified all configuration properties in spark and even in spark job web ui, local.dirs is shown as the folder i ve set.. How come it is still writing to /tmp.?

Comment: ideally it needs java tmp dir and spark local dirs, both of them were set to folders of our choice, not /tmp. I have debugged almost every corner and really fed up..

Comment: If you are using YARN. then yarn may be overriding it . http://badrit.com/blog/2015/2/29/running-spark-on-yarn#.VtR7HcfhiwQ

Comment: Hi, Ravindra, i can see the folders created in the directory, but they are with 700 permissions and my job is also failing with permission denied exception.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue disabling this properties on cloudera manager:

spark.shuffle.service.enabled

spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled

true -> false

Answer (score 0):

this work for my

on all nodes

sudo chmod -R 0777 /tmp
sudo chmod +t /tmp

with parallel-ssh

sudo parallel-ssh -h hosts.txt -l ubuntu --timeout=0 'sudo chmod -R 0777 /tmp'

sudo parallel-ssh -h hosts.txt -l ubuntu --timeout=0 'sudo chmod +t /tmp'