# Dataproc Spark returns java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.uncompressedLength(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;II) when accessing Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm moving from Dataproc 1.2 to 1.3. When I created a new Spark cluster on Dataproc using image version 1.3. I got

```
HiveMetaException: Metastore schema version is not compatible. Hive Version: 2.3.0, Database Schema Version: 2.1.0
```

because of database schema incompatibility. So I ssh-ed to Dataproc master instance and ran

```
schematool -dbType mysql -upgradeSchemaFrom 2.1.0
```

everything worked as expected. I then recreated a new Spark cluster to make sure it doesn't throw this exception again. However, when I ran

```
val df = spark.sql("select * from daily_active_user_trx")
df.show
```

on Zeppelin notebook and spark-shell, I got the following error.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 249, development-cluster-w-3.c.true-dmp.internal, executor 70): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.uncompressedLength(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;II)I
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.uncompressedLength(Native Method)
at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.uncompressedLength(Snappy.java:565)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.SnappyDecompressor.decompress(SnappyDecompressor.java:62)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.NonBlockedDecompressorStream.read(NonBlockedDecompressorStream.java:51)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
at org.apache.parquet.bytes.BytesInput$StreamBytesInput.toByteArray(BytesInput.java:205)
at org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainBinaryDictionary.<init>(PlainValuesDictionary.java:89)
at org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainBinaryDictionary.<init>(PlainValuesDictionary.java:72)
at org.apache.parquet.column.Encoding$1.initDictionary(Encoding.java:90)
at org.apache.parquet.column.Encoding$4.initDictionary(Encoding.java:149)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedColumnReader.<init>(VectorizedColumnReader.java:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.checkEndOfRowGroup(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:312)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextBatch(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:258)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:161)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:106)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:182)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:106)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.scan_nextBatch$(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.hasNext(InMemoryRelation.scala:139)
at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:216)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1092)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1083)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1018)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1083)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:809)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

After googling, I found a similar thread but it's on CDH

http://community.cloudera.com/t5/CDH-Manual-Installation/spark2-upgrade-to-2-3-0-from-2-2-0-wont-read-or-write-snappy/td-p/66735

I tried adding snappy-java-1.1.4.jar to /usr/lib/spark/jars on master node as suggested but it didn't work.

thanks

Peernat F.

Comment: you should hadoop add jars manually to your spark-sumbit or shell. example :  --jars /opt/hadoop/./hadoop-2.8.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/gcs-connector-1.6.5-hadoop2-shaded.jar ...

Answer (score 2):

This is [SPARK-24018](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24018), which the Dataproc team is currently working on addressing.

I believe to fix it you need the jar on all workers not just the master, which I why your fix did not work.

I would recommend a simple initialization action of:

```
rm -f /usr/lib/spark/jars/snappy*
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.1.2.6/snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar \
   -P /usr/lib/spark/jars
```

This should roll out to new Dataproc 1.3 images in a couple weeks after we are sure we fully understand the issue.

Comment: Nowadays the issue is fixed, according to Dataproc [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/release-notes#july_31_2018).