# Spark on Dataproc fails with java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

Spark job launched in Dataproc cluster fails with below exception. I have tried with various cluster configs but the result is same. I am getting this error in Dataproc image 1.2.

Note: There are no preemptive workers also there is sufficient space in the disks. However I have noticed that there is no `/hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root` folder at all in worker nodes. But I can see a folder named `dr.who`.

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to create local dir in /hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1534256335401_0001/blockmgr-89931abb-470c-4eb2-95a3-8f8bfe5334d7/2f.
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.getFile(DiskBlockManager.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.getFile(DiskBlockManager.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockResolver.getDataFile(IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

possible duplicate of : [Spark on Google's Dataproc failed due to java.io.FileNotFoundException: /hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229580/spark-on-googles-dataproc-failed-due-to-java-io-filenotfoundexception-hadoop)

Comment: @user3079777 can you pls provide details on any work-arounds that helped you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could resolve the issue by using Dataproc 1.3. 
However 1.3 does not come with bigquery connector which  needs to be handled . 
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/bigquery